# Python: ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999 while using win32com

Tags: python, win32com

I'm currently trying calculate the leadtime of all outlook messages within a specific outlook folder using python. In general the script runs fine however, after roundabout 2000 emails I received the following error (part of code):

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import time

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

folder = outlook.Folders("example@example.com")
inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")

messages = inbox.Items

df = pd.DataFrame()
index = 0
for msg in messages:
        if (msg.SenderEmailType != "EX"):
                print(str(msg.subject))
                print('Begin date:', msg.SentOn.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
                print('End date:',msg.LastModificationTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

                df.at[index, 'Subject'] = msg.subject
                df.at[index, 'Begin date'] = msg.SentOn.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                df.at[index, 'End date'] = msg.LastModificationTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I encounterd the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MailCounts.py", line 24, in <module>
    print('End date:',msg.LastModificationTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999
```

I tried to debug it  by selecting the specific email and put it into another outlook folder and then loop over it. But then it works fine without errors. So it seems to be folder specific?!

I have searched for several answers on the errors and the method in general. But as far as I can see, this answer was never asked before with a suitable answer. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please try printing out the value of `msg.LastModificationTime`. What does it contain?

Comment: Thanks! For the output see below: ```ExampleofSubjectTekst
Begin date: 2020-04-28``` followed by the error. So the error occurs on the print statement of msg.LastModificationTime

Comment: A succesfull msg.LastModificationTime is shown as follows: ```ExampleSubject1
Begindatum: 2020-04-28 18:31:07+00:00
Einddatum: 2020-06-03 11:03:36.748000+00:00``` without the strftime function and ```ExampleSubject2 Begindatum: 2020-04-28
Einddatum: 2020-06-03``` includinig the strftime function. I can't seem to print the msg.LastModificationTime for the specific email wthout the error occuring.

Comment: An important task in debugging is looking at an input value whose processing creates the error we are debugging. So please put your effort into getting the value which causes the error happening. Hint: `print(str(msg.LastModificationTime))` before your erroneous line should suffice. By the way, how are you getting the time (including zone) if your code contains `strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`?

Comment: I tried before but got the following output, print(str(msg.LastModificationTime)) at the specific email encounterd the following error: ```SubjectEmail1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Mailtjes tellen.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(str(msg.LastModificationTime))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 516, in __getattr__
    ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999``` Thanks btw for the help and quick response!

Comment: Regarding the second question I don't know excatly. It seems to me weird that while using the strftime functio I receive the error of microseconds while I explicity transform it to only a date type.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, it seems that outlook is the problem and not the code as shown above. The object outlook gives back to win32com is in such way that not a date-time object can be made thus giving the value error. Therefore giving the value error while using the strftime function. The only solution I found is except the error and continue with the loop. Not the ideal solution but it works I guess...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. If you have solved your problem, please post an answer (or close/delete your question). [Self answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) them are welcome here!

Comment: I found this only occurs when trying to access the LastModificationTime attribute. I replaced it with ReceivedTime and everything is working fine now. This assumes your use case allows you to use ReceivedTime instead of LastModificationTime , of course.

Comment: In my case, the error still happens even if not accessing the LastModificationTime attribute but with accessing SentOn and ReceivedTime. @StevenVanDorpe

Comment: This is a bug in pywin32. It will be fixed for good when https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1655 is released.

Comment: I am also having the same error. For me the problem comes from this line of code in the `win32com\client\dynamic.py` file: `ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)`. So far all attempts to correct it have failed and I really do need to correct it instead of bypassing it.

Comment: @Mike-SMT what's your python version and version of PyWin32 package you have installed?

Answer (score 2):

This was [a bug in PyWin32, reported as issue #1655](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1655).  It was fixed by [pull request #1683](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/pull/1683), which was merged on 7th of May 2021.

The earliest release after that date is [release 301, from the 31st of May 2021](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases/tag/b301).  I would suggest upgrading to at least that version, using whatever package manager you happen to be using.  Though preferably to the latest stable version.

Comment: The bug is back then since I just started getting this error this week in 2023.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Are you sure you have upgraded?

Comment: Of coarse this venv is on 3.7 instead of 3.10 like the rest of my projects XD. Looks like the installed version is 227.